# MUI Modal overlay ionic select popups

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, material-ui

I have a react application in which I use the MUI lib, but I still use ionic in most of the code.

**DESCRIPTION**
Upon opening MUI modal windows that contain ionic selects inside, the select modals get overlapped by the MUI modal window, blocking the user from using the site.

**Reason:**
The modal window of the MUI is rendered based on its portal, while ionic lies in a different context.
So there is a problem of incompatibility of libraries that use different approaches.
A clear example in the sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ionic-react-select-icon-bug-forked-jotf5q?file=/src/App.tsx

In order to fix the problem of course we can use our own select with popup solution instead ionic select, but I just wondering if it's possible to fix this but ( that I provided in codesandbox), another way.

Update:
Look that it relates to root styles .ion-page, but still wondering how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason behind that is that MUI is appending the modal outside the ion-app/root app.

my solution for this is to add a container to Mui Modal like

`<Modal container={document.querySelector("ion-app")} >`

Comment: I play with overflow and z-indexes, but you solution is fine, thank you!